# Is there any six stage rocket?

Tags: launch

In all the history of the rockets was there any rocket with six or more stages?

I know ASLV, [Minotaur V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_V) and [Jason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_(rocket)) sounding rocket had five stages but I don't know any rocket with six stages.